# Windows 10 Activation Error

Tags: windows-10

I have made a mistake activating a new machine. I entered the new machines product key into the wrong machine which was already activated with a digital licence.

Both machines are Win 10 ver 20H2.

I know I can uninstall that key using `slmgr.vbs /upk` but will the machine revert to its digital license or would I have to buy a new licence for it?

Comment: You just change the key back to the original key.

Comment: If you have the key for that machine, re enter it after running upk. It should activate

Comment: I can't do that. The machine was originally activated with the RTM version and never had a key.